# Does an F/A-18 require a lot of rudder in turns?

Tags: aerodynamics, pilot-technique, rudder, fa-18

I am an aspiring Navy fighter pilot and I use an X-Plane add on for FA-18 Hornet as a fighter. It's made by a creator named Colimata. I think the turns are unrealistic. When I begin a bank a lot of rudder is required to keep coordinated. Does anyone know if this is realistic?

Comment: No that doesn't sound at all right.  Pretty sure the F-18's digital flight control systems include a yaw damper functionality so it's hard to see how you would have to center the brick/ball with rudder; the computers should be doing it.  You should probably try the DCS F-18 which I have heard is a pretty realistic one.

Comment: Eagle Dynamics has a pretty detailed F/A-18 module within their DCS product, you may want to give that a try. That sim does represent a pretty efficient yaw damper, as John K points out; the rudder is rarely touched outside of cross-wind takeoffs and landings.

Comment: You likely need to enable the Yaw Damper on the autopilot controls.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I used to be an avionics instructor teaching maintenance type courses for the F/A-18. I have plenty of hours flying in the simulator where I would get the students to conduct navigation flights to familiarise themselves with the operation of the instruments as well as flight controls. I can confirm 100% that the rudder is barely touched once airborne. There is no need to co-ordinate turns as the flight control system does it for you. These things are incredibly easy to fly. It is the controlling of your radios, weapons, FLIR, navigating and keeping an eye on the RADAR all at the same time that is the hard part.

Answer (score 0):

Rudder isn't required or used for most flight operations.

This is true of most turbojet aircraft, too.